# #1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I need to modify MySQL code to pass this error and get the same result.

---

**I use localhost with Xampp ..**

- Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.1
- Server type: MariaDB
- Server version: 10.1.30-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
- Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407
- PhpMyAdmin Version information: 4.7.4, latest stable version: 4.9.1

```sql
CREATE VIEW product_variation_stock_view AS
                SELECT 
                    product_variations.product_id AS product_id,
                    product_variations.id AS product_variation_id,
                    COALESCE(SUM(stocks.quantity) - COALESCE(SUM(product_variation_order.quantity), 0), 0) AS stock,
                    CASE WHEN COALESCE(SUM(stocks.quantity) - COALESCE(SUM(product_variation_order.quantity), 0), 0) > 0
                        THEN true
                        ELSE false
                    END in_stock
                FROM product_variations
                LEFT JOIN(
                    SELECT stocks.product_variation_id AS id,
                    SUM(stocks.quantity) AS quantity
                    FROM stocks
                    GROUP BY stocks.product_variation_id
                ) AS stocks USING (id)
                LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT
                        product_variation_order.product_variation_id AS id,
                        SUM(product_variation_order.quantity) AS quantity
                    FROM product_variation_order
                    GROUP BY product_variation_order.product_variation_id
                ) AS product_variation_order USING (id)
                GROUP BY product_variations.id
```

MySQL said:

> #1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: which mysql version are you using workbench and mysql 8 haven't a problem with it

Comment: i use localhost with xampp .. Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.1 | 
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 | phpmyadmin Version information: 4.7.4, latest stable version: 4.9.1

Comment: please use select @@version in phpmyadmin

Comment: 10.1.30-MariaDB @nbk

Comment: @nbk is it correct ?

Comment: @nbk Server type: MariaDB
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 10.1.30-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Comment: It is too confusing (to me, and maybe to the parser) to have table names and aliases the same.  Example: `stocks`.  Please rename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**upgrade to mysql-8 and my problem is solved.**

---

> To Upgrade MySql included in XAMPP (I did it on a Windows system):
>
> 1. Rename your Mysql directory to some other name.
> 2. Download the .msi file from the MariaDB link https://downloads.mariadb.org/.
> 3. Run .msi.  Change the install directory to your Mysql location under                XAMPP.
> 4. After completion, copy the old my.ini from the original mysql/bin directory to your new mysql/bin directory.
> 5. You should be able to start Mysql from the XAMPP control panel.

I found the solution here
http://www.mynotebucket.com/update-mysql-under-xmpp/

Comment: Please file a bug against MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your MySQL. If for any reason you are unable to do so, you can create views for the subqueries and integrate them into your query.